# min-width: 1920px not firing off correctly

Tags: html, css

My **@media screen and (min-width: 1920px)** is not firing off until changing the min-width to 1396px on a 1920x1080 screen. There is no zoom on the browser and the attempt to account for the scroll bar (must be a few px in size) shows that it's something more.

I'm fairly certain that no other CSS overrides this block, as it's the last block in the file.

CSS:

The default h1 element:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'leaguegothic';
    color: #d2ff00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 40vh;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

The override on screensize:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 200pt;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 50pt;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>CREATIVE<br>DIGITAL<br>DESIGN</h1>
```

Full Source:

https://jsfiddle.net/9evuv1z9/

Comment: For me, its loading correctly the media query style ([screenshot](https://image.prntscr.com/image/PqgsTVDdSLSNkNM2U8ZAiw.png))

Comment: Do you have a browser window which is wider than 1920px? (Not device pixels, but CSS pixels). Try to zoom out to emulate that, then you'll see it happening in your fiddle.

Comment: When using dev tools to set the width to 1920, everything works as expected. I could imagine the scroll bar may cause an issue, but the scroll bar is definitely not 500+px

Comment: Also zooming out to 80% causes the intended css to load correctly

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I have a 1920x1080 screen and it doesn't render properly on it unless zoomed to 80% even when compensating for the scroll bar

Comment: That media query doesn't measure the screen, but the viewport, in this case the browser window. Obviously your browser window isn't 1920px wide or wider.

Comment: However it doesn't render properly until 1396px. How is the viewport ever seen as larger than 1396px?

Comment: sounds like a zooming issue to me

Comment: Solved by setting the Windows desktop scaling from the default 125% to 100%

Comment: so it *was*  a zooming issue...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting the Windows desktop scaling from the default 125% to 100%